# how to fix pushing and popping error?

Tags: unity, c#, gui

when i write a code with begin and end area ,i get this error,
though i did it right,am quite sure that EndArea() is executed in the algorithmic flow of the code,and not escaped ,how to fix that??

the summary of the code:

```
 void OnGUI() {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100));
        some code
              -  if (statement)
               -   for {}
                -other
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
```

Comment: I am afraid with currently provided information, this question is not possible to answer. Can you provide more details on the error and the piece of code causing it?

Comment: the log shows this: GUI Error: You are pushing more GUIClips than you are popping.

Comment: i read about it they said if you dont close the area this error occur,but i closed the area ,and i wrote the summary of the code as requested by the site policy

Comment: The current summary of your code isn't detailed enough. Show a short code snippet that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If your asking a question about debug, and we can not replicate your problem with the code, your question is offtopic. Note that if you just dump *all* of your code, as done previously, your question could *still* be considered off topic as not *minimal*.

Comment: If you have a bunch of nested if/for blocks in between your BeginArea and EndArea calls, then the most likely culprit is a misplaced or absent brace somewhere, leading to one of your begins/ends being executed only conditionally, or multiple times, because it's slipped into an unexpected control flow path. To verify this, we'd have to see the actual code between/around the area calls. As Gnemlock says, a minimal sample is best - try copying your script and deleting code until the problem disappears, to narrow down which lines play a role, eliminating distractions that don't affect the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Managing resources (clip area in this case could be seen as a resource) is not trivial especially in programs with complex control flow. While this question was originally about debugging a specific case, I would rather suggest leveraging C# tools of handling resources - namely implement the [IDispoable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface/pattern and solve the problem universally.
A very minimalist example for clipping could look like this:

```
public class ClipArea : IDisposable
{
    // Track whether Dispose has been called.
    private bool disposed = false;

    public ClipArea(Rect area)
    {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(area));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(!this.disposed)
        {
            if(disposing) GUILayout.EndArea();
            disposed = true;
        }
   }

  ~ClipArea() { Dispose(false); }
}
```

*note: implementing IDisposable correctly is not trivial, see linked MSDN page or other renomed resources for details* 
 
This implementation of `ClipArea` can be used within [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, which ensures freeing resource(=clip), replacing all your `BeginArea`/`EndArea` calls.

```
using(var ca = new ClipArea(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100)))
{//note opening parenthesis, the syntax is similar to if statement
   //your complex code here e.g.
    some code
       -  if (statement)
          -   for {}
       -other
   //you can also nest using statements or call methods
}//at this point .EndArea() will be called automatically no matter what
 //even when exception was thrown within your code
```

---

important note under line: **do not mix** `using`/`IDisposable` with bare approach - if you manually call `BeginArea` elsewhere you are still responsible to call `EndArea` at correct time, possibly re-introducing the bug. If you do the `using` approach exclusively poping clips *should* never cause problems.

*included code is illustrative - not tested*